# Bound on line with minimum zone complexity in a line arrangement

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-geometry, upper-bounds

In an arrangement of $n$ (pseudo)lines, the well known [Zone Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_theorem) gives a $O(n)$ bound on the complexity of the zone of any given line (for the purpose of this question, the complexity of the zone of a line $\ell$ is the sum of the number of edges over all faces bounded by $\ell$). The sharpest version of the theorem gives an upper bound of $9.5n - 3$, which is tight.

My question is the following: Can the constant $9.5$ be improved significantly if instead of looking at an arbitrary line in the arrangement we look at the one minimizing its zone complexity? For example, is it true that in any arrangement of $n$ (pseudo)lines there is a line whose zone complexity is at most $8n + O(1)$? Has anything like this ever been asked or published? What is the best known (if anything below $9.5$)?

(This question might arguably be better suited to the maths stackexchange, but I'm guessing discrete and computational geometers are more present here)